# Slow sftp.mget when pulling a large number of files (10,000+)

Tags: ftp, sftp, mget

We are pulling thousands of files (10,000+) from a remote server by a wildcard.  The files are small, and the performance of the transfer itself fine.  However, the implicit "ls *.856*" performance is awful.  Supposedly the file listing logic has an implicit sort, so the large number of files has significant overhead. Ideally, mget would start transferring as soon as it finds the first match.

Any suggestions or thoughts on how to do this better?

Comment: `rsync` might be your best solution.

Comment: Our system is RHEL 7.  No idea on the remote system.   This is a BASH script.

Comment: Why would rsync be an improvement?